# How to use .where and check a self condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I want to get all the games that are not full, ie, has empty spot in the table.
The available number of spots is the `nplayer` attribute of my model Game.

I have a helper to get the current number_of_players that are already in a game: `number_of_players(game)`

I am trying the following to show the games that have room space:

```
@opengames = Game.where("nplayer > ?", number_of_players(***game***))
```

My problem is: what should I use inside my helper number_of_game(xxxx).

How can I tell .*where* to check the game that it is trying to find? Is it possible or should I get all the games, and than compare one by one? Like:

```
@opengames = []    
@games = Game.all
    @games.each do |game|
      if game.nplayer > number_of_players(game) 
            @opengames.push game
      end
    end
```

(Sorry if my explanation is not clear... english is not my native language)

Comment: can you post `number_of_players` method?

Comment: Inside Application Helper `module ApplicationHelper
    
  def number_of_players (game)
  @decks.where(game:game).count
  end
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

```
@opengames = Game.all.select { |game| game.nplayer > number_of_players(game) }
```

However it will be more cleaner if you can perform `number_of_players` at db level only. For instance if games and decks are associated, you can perform

```
Game.where("`games`.`nplayer` > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `decks` WHERE `decks`.`game_id` = `games`.`id`)")
```

Comment: to me your first "try" is perfect, select worked perfectly!